# print the string by removing the PRIME ASCII CHARACTERS

Tags: java, c#, c++, c

I don't understand this question pls help, How to show prime ascii character, I've one question in java that I've to show prime ascii charater, Now how to get prime ascii character? can you please help me regarding this question. How is it possible?

For e.g, let's understand this:

**Input**

```
4
MEHTA
Mehta
HELLO
hello
```

**Output**

```
MEHTA
Mht
HELL
hllo
```

I don;t understand here in this example why `e` is removed from `mehta`? Please tell me what's happening here?

**EDITED**

Why from `MEHTA`

`E` and `A` is not removed??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is tag spamming.

Comment: No all questions are allowed using any programming language ....**this is not a spam** ...pls :(

Comment: This question is regarding all programming languages..

Comment: The answer is in this table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Can you pls explain me with a simple example, I'm sorry that i'm taking from you a little efforts.. but pls help me to understand this question

Comment: If you read the link posted by @RobbyCornelissen you will see that every character is represented by an code.Now what you have to do is look on that table, find the ASCII code of every character given as input and to print only the characters of that word that have the ASCII code as prime number.It's easy if you read that link.

Comment: Then why has the '4' been removed, ASCII value 52?

Comment: I don'it understand the question. What is a "prime ascii character" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look at the decimal value for the ASCII characters as listed in [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart).

If that value is a prime number, you need to remove the character.

For example:

```
M  78
e  101  -> Is prime number
h  104
t  116
a  97   -> Is prime number
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i've little thing need to ask, please see my edited question

Comment: The uppercase characters have different values. `A` is 65, `E` is 69. Both not prime.

Comment: Thank you very much :) ... I appreciate your guidance ... Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes now finally i understand :) thanks once agan!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means the characters who stand at prime numbers..like 'e' stands at position 5 in the list of alphabets and 5 is a prime number. That is what I can make out from the list of input and outputs provided. Can you please share more inputs and corresponding outputs so that we have a little more clarification on what is the aim of the question.

Comment: I agree with Robby Cornelissen. Please refer the table and look for the decimal representation of any character to find if its prime or not